# How can i filter pivot table with One to Many relation inside - Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

### Tables

For example, i have 4 tables:

[Tables Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ympk.png)

### Models

```php
// PlacedBet
public function odds()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Odd::class, 'placed_bets_has_odds');
}
```

```php
// Odd
public function placedBets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(PlacedBet::class, 'placed_bets_has_odds');
}
```

```php
// Result
public function placedBetsOdds()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PlacedBetOdd::class);
}
```

```php
// PlacedBetOdd
public function result()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Result::class);
}
```

### Issue

I want all PlacedBets where placed_bets_has_odds.result_id equal null. But i don't know how can i do that with Eloquent in my PlacedBetRepository file.

Thank you for your help

Comment: there is no relation between PlaceBets and result model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [whereDoesntHave](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) to get null relationships.

```
PlaceBets::whereDoesntHave('results)->get();
```

But as @Naveed Ali has implied in the comment, you would need to place a results relationship in the PlaceBets model;

```
public function results()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Result::class, 'placed_bets_has_odds');
}
```